# Why was this question about making sure one's car doesn't get impounded/ticketed closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [How can I make sure my car doesn't get impounded/ticketed before the 72h parking deadline in Seattle, or at least, prove it wasn't parked over 72h?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168857/1810) was closed as off-topic, which surprised me because a car is used to travel, and parking one's car is part of traveling by car. Why was it closed as off-topic?

In my case, the context of the question is that I was traveling by car in Seattle, stayed at some Airbnb for 3 days, and the  neighbor complained after a few hours that I parked in the street: the Airbnb owner told me they saw my California plate and didn't like it for whatever reason. I could legally park for [72h](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/168836/1810), however I was concerned that the neighbor may lie to the police and claim that the car was parked for over 72h, hence my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll copy here the answer that question received in the [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130285/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-make-sure-my-car-doesnt) from mod [Rory Alsop](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2260/rory-alsop):

> - Some parking questions may be, others will not be. Like not all questions about cars are on topic on Mechanics.SE. And not all questions about cyber hacking are on topic at Security.SE
> - The issue is that you repeat this same behaviour any time any of your posts are closed, without necessarily fixing the issue. Your reaction always seems to be to try and find examples that should mean your post remains open, rather than look at your posts and how they fit (or don't fit) the site scope.
> - My guidance to you is to sort out your posts rather than complain when you have a post closed and then hunt around for examples as to why yours should be opened again.
>   Your tactic only alienates the community, it doesn't show you improving your approach, and it causes the community and mods to expend effort. This is not really acceptable.
>   When you get 5 close votes from the community, your first assumption should be that your post is not up to scratch.  Don't assume it is good and you should prove to us why. We will almost always trust 5 folks more than 1.

I disagree, but the current ratio of downvotes:upvotes on the original question and the meta question seems to indicate I'm in the minority.